# Insert a value in a Mysql database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, input, insert

I am trying to insert values typed from me to a MySQL database. I am using python 3.4 and mysql.connector. Here is the part of the script:

```
Value = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 10: "))
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Number', Value )""")
```

I am actually trying to find out how to get what i am inserting from my keyboard into the second field of the test table. As it is right now it gives me a SQL syntax error. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cursor.execute`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) to bind `Value` into your query.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Number', %s)", (Value,))
```

This is preferable over the other answers because it protects against SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

Use string formatting to provide the Value variable

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Number', %s)""" % Value)
```